# How to combine: INDEX + MATCH + ?VLOOKUP?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having an issue with INDEX + MATCH combination:

```
=INDEX(ALL!$C$1:$I$1,MATCH(TRUE,ALL!C2:I2<>0,0))
```

At the moment the aforementioned formula does this job to an extent, where if it finds <>0 value in a row it will return header from this specific column. The issue is that the ROW (as above C2:I2) needs to be specified.

I need to vlookup values in the column "A" in sheet "ALL" and based on that, look at corresponding rows between C:I and if the value in that specific row is <>0 then return heading value.

[image]

So, in green I would need a formula to pick up numbers from "Data Source" headings, based on value 1 or any value <>0. I'm guessing it all leads somehow to some sort of "vlookup" hybrid.

Any ideas how to combine vlookup in it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide some examplary data of the data input and desired output?  I know you have described it in the question, but I'm not sure if I understood it properly (ideally edited into the original question)

Comment: I think you need to clarify whether you need to look in just one row or several rows and what happens if there is more than one match.

Comment: @Rawrplus - done. The list is dynamic and changes, thus ideally we can look at the entire columns. There is no duplicates at all.

Comment: @WestRay much better, thanks

Comment: You can use SUMIF if there is only one '1' per row, you would need something like =SUMIF(INDEX(B:E,MATCH(G2,A:A,0),0),">0",$B$1:$E$1) but I won't have time to post it properly till later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there can only be one '1' per row, I was thinking of this

```
=SUMIF(INDEX(B:E,MATCH(G2,A:A,0),0),">0",$B$1:$E$1)
```

[image]

Otherwise if there can be more than one '1'

```
=INDEX($B$1:$E$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B:E,MATCH(G2,A:A,0),0)>0,0))
```

to match the first value greater than zero, in this case entered as an array formula.

Answer (score 0):

A simple [**`=SUMIF()`**](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php) formula will do, no other convoluted `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` nested formulas required.

> Let's presume we have a data-table that starts at `B2` and end at
>   `F6`, like this:
>
> [image]

So now, to comprehend the solution, here's the syntax of `SUMIF()` formula *(`Function`)*:

```
=SUMIF( range, criteria, [sum_range] )
```

So, what we want to do is:

1. go over the `range` of `C3:F3` (and each other respective row)
2. the `criteria` to when to sum, is when this `range` contains `1`
3. and we want to `sum_range` (sum up) fixed array of numbers, so `$C$2:$F$2`

---

So the result is (for row 3):

```
=SUMIF(C3:F3,1,$C$2:$F$2)
```

and we drag the formula down, producing expected result:

[image]

---

**PS:** I think this illustrates the point very well, as to why it's important to declare not only what your formula is doing **but also, what you're trying to as in whole** as there often is a better (easier) way to implement something, that you might not have thought of.

In other words, follow the [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi, I think you have created some new dataset? Also, I did not asked for "sums" but to return heading (which is either 100,200,300 or 400).

Comment: Can there be more than a single `1` in a single row? If not, then the formula will work for your purpose

Comment: Have you tried the formula I have initially used? The problem with it is that it is confined to a specific row (just like what you have provided). The Data Source and the List changes and it has 1000's of rows. It definitely requires vlookup.

Comment: Look at the comment above. If there is a single `1` per row (doesn't matter how many rows or columns there are) it will always return the correct "heading"

Comment: It will not work, I'm sorry. The names of the animals change order in the list (randomly) every time I run VBA code etc. Your assumption is static. That is the very issue I had with my formula (which already worked in the same way as your solution). There is a need for vlookup /or/ index /or/ match /or/ more than likely all of them together.

Comment: So... that begs the question then, why not just create a pivot table?

Comment: I do not need a pivot table. I need a formula. Thanks for your effort tho.